# if statement glitching

Tags: c#, if-statement, xna

It appears that my if statement is not working; it is, from what I gather with debug messageboxes that I placed earlier throughout the code to report variables etc., simply not modifying the variable "pos" in the if block, but the if block is definitely being executed. It's hard to explain.

I'm building a little game with cars on a street, and here, I try to spawn new cars and assign them a starting position (or modify their position) based on the lane of the street they're in. This is not production code, it's just me roughing out the basic idea.

```
for (int i = 0; i < carlane.Count; i++)
{
    float lane = carlane.ElementAt(i);
    if (lane == 1)
    {
        if (carpos.Count <= i)
        {
            pos = new Vector2(screenWidth - 20, (screenHeight / 2) - (8 * screenHeight / 200));
        }
        else
        {
            pos = new Vector2(carpos[i].X - 2, carpos[i].Y);
        }
        rotation = 1.5f * (float)Math.PI;
    }
    else if (lane == 2)
    {
        if (carpos.Count <= i)
        {
            pos = new Vector2(screenWidth - 20, (screenHeight / 2) - (8 * screenHeight / 200));
        }
        else
        {
            pos = new Vector2(carpos[i].X - 2, carpos[i].Y);
        }
        rotation = 1.5f * (float)Math.PI;
    }
}

spriteBatch.Draw(car, pos, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, (lane - 1) * (float)Math.PI * 0.5f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

if (carpos.Count > i)
{
     carpos[i] = (pos);
}
else
{
     carpos.Add(pos);
}
```

And so, when lane is set to 1, nothing happens. Cars spawn, but don't appear. When lane is set to 2, I purposefully used the same code within the if-block as when lane is equal to 1, and the cars spawn and drive along the lane correctly. Something is wrong with the code, when lane = 1, and I don't know what it is.

My computer runs Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, and I'm using C# 2010 express edition with XNA game studio 4.0.

Please help?

Comment: you should remove "C# XNA" from the title, since those are tags and you already added those tags

Comment: What happens to `pos` and `rotation` after the `if`s? After the loop?

Comment: @Andrei They're used to draw sprites of cars using spriteBatch.Draw.

Comment: Can you show the code? At least to the end of the `for` or maybe until `pos` and `rotation` are used? I think the root of the problem is there.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not enough information here to know what's going on for sure, but if you used the [Visual Studio Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging), than you should have no trouble determining exactly which lines your code is hitting and tracking the value of `pos`

Comment: I added all the relevant code - I'll try using the visual studio debugger in the meantime.

Comment: Set some break-points for the debugger inside each of the `if` statements. Then step through your code and test your understanding of what it is doing. You may also want to use conditional breakpoints so that execution is stopped only when a variable is a certain value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When lane equals 1, the scale `(lane - 1) * (float)Math.PI * 0.5f` equals 0, which means that car is scaled to nothing - thus nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: Actually that's the rotation - but how do I fix this, then? Do I enclose the spriteBatch.Draw in an if statement, to determine if lane is equal to 1 and draw the sprite differently, or is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: You sure that's the rotation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx

Comment: @user1762453, rotation is the 5th parameter of this method. The fix depends on how you want `lane` to affect the way car is drawn.

Comment: My bad - I misread my own code! Thanks for the help, you both helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When `lane` is zero, `(lane - 1) * (float)Math.PI * 0.5f` is zero. You're `Draw`ing with `scale` argument zero, which draws nothing.

The documentation:

```
public void Draw (
         Texture2D texture,
         Vector2 position,
         Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
         Color color,
         float rotation,
         Vector2 origin,
         float scale,
         SpriteEffects effects,
         float layerDepth
)
```

Your code:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(
         car,
         pos,
         null,
         Color.White,
         rotation,
         origin,
         (lane - 1) * (float)Math.PI * 0.5f,
         SpriteEffects.None,
         0f
);
```

Looks like the scale to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should only change the `pos` variable depending on the lane, not the size of the sprite (you were changing the scale of the sprite, just set that to 1.0f).

```
    spriteBatch.Draw(car, pos, null, Color.White, rotation, 
                 origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```